# How to change Bootstrap navbar style on tablet

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to change the navbar on tablets ans smartphones so that it looks like this :
http://sdz-upload.s3.amazonaws.com/prod/upload/img064.JPG

Actually my standard navbar looks like that :

```html
<header class="container col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

      <!-- Navigation
      ================================================== -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" role="navigation">
        <a href="#page-top" class="navbar-brand">La maison de l'architecture</a>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="hidden"><a href="#page-top"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#accueil" class="active">Accueil</a></li>
          <li><a href="#qui">Qui sommes-nous ?</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default), you are not using the correct navbar.

Here is what you should use:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">La maison de l'architecture</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#accueil" class="active">Accueil</a></li>
        <li><a href="#qui">Qui sommes-nous ?</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: I tried your example and i modified a little, i changed like this : https://jsfiddle.net/byryrj8k/   Anyway you really helped me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By using **bootstrap** you can achieve the navbar exactly like that.
For more details [click here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">La maison de l'architecture</a>
    </div>


    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Accueil</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Qui sommes-nous ?</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
  
<div class="container">
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
  <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Using media Query you can change it.

```
/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: landscape) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}
```